Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:3.0.0-M1:deploy
I am having some issues in pushing some artifacts in nexus. This is happening during the mvn deploy phase and I am getting this error
Error:  Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:3.0.0-M1:deploy (default) on project...text: ArtifactDeployerException: Failed to deploy artifacts: Could not transfer artifact
This is happening because during the same mvn deploy step just earlier this artifact was already deployed, and this is on the release nexus repository, so it's expected to fail.
Do you have an idea why would this happen? (pushing the same artifact twice during the same mvn deploy phase) ?
Everything it's working fine when pushing in nexus to snapshots path.
Thank you!
tried mvn clean deploy, did not work

First why using such an old version of the plugin (https://maven.apache.org/plugins/) and the error looks like a problem with network/firewall or alike? but the rest of the error output is missing...

A guess... if it is the exact same artifact that won't be allowed by default in Nexus Repo. Re-deploying the exact same version is an ant-pattern, you will not be able to tell which deploy is in any given build.  If you really want to do this any how change the repository configuration to allow redeploys.
